# Using a type constructor in a type refinement

Tags: scala, typeclass

I'm having a problem which is probably best expressed in code - a simplified example below:

```
abstract class MainTC[A] {
  type E
  // A type constructor for the implementing type:
  type CN[_]  
  implicit val ev: CN[A] =:= A  // check that CN works as a type constructor for A
  def get(self: A): E
  def set[B](self: A, other: B): CN[B] { type E = B }
  def convert[B](self: A)(implicit conv: Convert[A, E, B]) = conv.convert(self)(this)
}

abstract class Convert[A, _E, B] {
  type Out
  def convert(self: A)(implicit isMain: MainTC[A] { type E = _E }): Out 
}
object Convert {
  implicit def convertDoubleToInt[A, _CN[_]](implicit 
    isMain: MainTC[A] { type E = Double; type CN[_] = _CN[_] },
  ): Convert[A, Double, Int] = new Convert[A, Double, Int] {
    type Out = _CN[Int] { type E = Int }
    def convert(self: A): Out = {
      val toInt = isMain.get(self).toInt
      isMain.set[Int](self, toInt)
      // type mismatch - 
      // found: isMain.CN[Int]{type E = Int} (which expands to) _CN[_]{type E = Int}
      // required: this.Out (which expands to) _CN[Int] {type E = Int}
    }
  }
}
```

The basic situation here is quite simple - I am using a typeclass to implement the polymorphic `convert` function. The tricky part is that I am storing a type constructor as an abstract type within the `MainTC` typeclass. When converting in the `Convert` typeclass, I would then like to use that type constructor to create a new type as the output type (eg, `CN[Int]`). I am trying to use something like the `Aux` pattern to achieve this, with `_CN[_]` being created as a type alias for `isMain.CN[_]`. However, it's not working (error message in the code). If anyone could lend me a hand I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean `type CN[_] = _CN[_]` or `type CN[X] = CN[X]`? If you change it to the latter, you run into the issue that

```scala
def convert(self: A): Out
```

can't implement

```scala
def convert(self: A)(implicit isMain: MainTC[A] { type E = _E }): Out
```

because it's missing the implicit parameter. Keep in mind that Scala implicits don't have to be coherent: `convertDoubleToInt`'s `(isMain: MainTC[A] {type E = _ E}).TC` isn't the same as `convert`'s `(isMain: MainTC[A] {type E = _ E}).TC`

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm using the `type CN[_] = _CN [_]` refinement not to actually set isMainTC.CN[_], but to make _CN[_] into an alias for it, so that I can use _CN[_] in the other implicit parameters. Similar to the `Aux` pattern.

Comment: Double check: Do you mean to say that the typeconstructor `CN[_]` is a type constructor for the wildcard type `_CN[_]` for all types? In other words, that `type CN[X] = (_CN[A] forSome { type A })`

Comment: I want to make `_CN[_]` itself into a type constructor, so I can later use it in `type Out = _CN[Int]`

Comment: `_CN[A]` is a typeconstructor already since that's declared in `convertDoubleToInt`'s signature. `type CN[X] = _CN[_]`  just means that `CN[X]`  for any `X` now is equal to the wildcard existential `_CN[_]` (or `_CN[A] forSome { type A} `), not that it's equal to `_CN[X]` for the same `X`

Comment: @Chrisper see also https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YHUEwXEmQlmlhyq4WerEMQ

Comment: thanks - I'm not sure if the intention of the code is clear, but I am looking for some way to pass the abstract type constructor `CN[_]` in `MainTC` into the body of `convertDoubleToInt` so that I can then use it to create a `CN[Int]` type for `Out`. Would a type lambda be more appropriate here?

Comment: that Scastie example succinctly nails the problem - I'm going to return to this tomorrow morning but thanks, this has given me some useful pointers already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223753/discussion-between-martijn-and-chrisper).